# Choose a different executable name in a "go-getable" package

Tags: go

Is it possible to have a cli-package (`package main`) which is "go-getable", but the binary is installed under a different name?

For example to have a repository
github.com/exaring/foo-cli

But `go get github.com/foo/foo-cli` would install a binary called `foo` (not `foo-cli`)?

The point is to have an expressive repository name but a short and easy to type executable.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with programming. Just stick your main into github.com/foo/foo-cli/cmd/foo and there you go.

Comment: Who said it was a programming problem? It's a tooling question! I hoped that there might be a modifier like the build constrains. Something like `//name:foo`. Well, never mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with the user running `go build` instead of `go get`, you can do this:

```
go build -o foo github.com/foo/foo-cli
```

Otherwise, you can keep all the CLI code in `foo-cli` and put the `main` function in `foo`.

Comment: Thanks, masnun. The go-getable part is essential here. I want users to type `go get github.com/foo/foo-cli` to install the binary in their $GOPATH/bin. Looks like this is not possible right now.